# Windows Service not working when installed, works fine in Debug mode; crashes on Moving/deleting files

Tags: c#, .net, service

I created a windows service which watches a directory. When a file is dumped into it, it takes the data and puts it into a database. Then this file is moved to another directory and deleted. It works fine in debug mode. But when i install it on my computer it stops after throwing the data into the database and the file in question is neither moved or deleted. I suspect a permission issue is involved. I tried to create a event log:

```
public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";         
    }
```

So i have three questions. 
(1) What could be causing my service to work as described in debug but fail when installed on my computer.(2) I have initiated a event log as shown above. But do i need to add other code to record the event of my service stopping. I presume this would be done in a 'override onShutdown' method.(3) Finally when my service stops, i want to look at the event log. But i do not know how to do this, is in administrative tools? stored as a file on some directory?

Here is edit to this post in lieu of the grateful advice given below.

```
      try
        {
            File.Move(e.FullPath, finalString);
            File.Delete(e.FullPath);
        }
        catch(Exception q)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("MySource", q.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);

            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fmd"], true))
            {
                w.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"));
                w.Write(q.ToString());
            }
        }
```

As per suggestion i put a try-catch around the file move and delete plus i added a OnShutdown method:

```
 protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ond"], true))
        {
            w.Write("stop OnShutdown");
        }
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("MySource", message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```

I do not know how to pass any system error message to the shutdown method, so any advice appreciated. When i installed my modified code as a service, it again stopped before moving or deleting the files. Neither of my two logs accessed by a stream recorded anything. Plus the event viewer showed nothing either?

Comment: "the file in question is neither moved or deleted" add a try-catch around it, and in case of an error write that error with all information available to the log. The reason for the failure will likely be stated there.

Comment: Please at my modified post, i was unable to record any exception?1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the reason for all the commotion. I eventually found some logs in the event viewer. They were listed in Administrative events in custom logs. There were three error logs: .Net runtime; Application error & Service Control Manager. In '.Net Runtime' the stack showed a unhandled exception for system.windows.forms. I stupidly included a pop up box in my release version. But even when i commented this away; i got a error. So i went back and found other message boxes, primarily in try catch statements. Removed these and solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can write as following,

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
   EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "Application");    

EventLog.WriteEntry("MySource", message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

to view the event log messages, Goto Administrator Tools -> Event Viewer and look for the source you have created. or Just simply type eventvwr in run window.

When Services installed, it works under SYSTEM User account where service might not have access to some resources. Please put logs and see where exactly the issue is.

If you service installed in your development machine, use attach to process option under DEBUG Menu in Visual Studio to find out.

Comment: Please at my modified post, i was unable to record any exception or view one?!

Answer (score 1):

> What could be causing my service to work as described in debug but fail when installed on my computer?

Permissions. The service is likely running under `LocalSystem` or `Network Service` if you didn't provide a different identity.

> I have initiated a event log as shown above. But do i need to add other code to record the event of my service stopping. I presume this would be done in a 'override onShutdown' method?

Yes, you're assumption is correct.

> Finally when my service stops, i want to look at the event log. But i do not know how to do this, is in administrative tools?

Just hit <kbd>Windows Key+R</kbd> to get the `Run` dialog and type `eventvwr`.

Comment: Please look at my modified post, unable to record or view errors?!